# Scheme Confusing of Let and Let*

Tags: scheme, let

```
(let ((x 2) (y 3)
  (let ((x 7)
        (z (+ x y)))
    (* z x)))
```

With the code above, why is the answer 35, not 70?  In the second `let`, x is 7 so z should be 7 + 3 = 10, and then the result should be 7 * 10 = 70. I know got another is let* I am very confusing between this 2. The sample is grabs from google. I already google but just can't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is still bound to the outer `let` when calling `(+ x y)`.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Leppie's answer: if you had written

```
(let ((x 2) (y 3))
    (let* ((x 7)
           (z (+ x y)))
       (* z x)))
```

you would get the answer you expected. The internal `let*` is exactly equivalent to

```
(let ((x 7))
    (let ((z (+ x y)))
       (* z x)))
```

and in fact might be implemented that way in some Schemes.

In other words, in a `let*` form each successive binding after the first is in the scope of all the previously created bindings.