# How to express let* as a lambda expression (not the regular let)

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme, sicp, let

I have a scheme related question, how can we implement let* as a lambda expression. To be more precise, I am not wondering about the "regular" let, but the let with * which lets us use one let expression within another.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003518/confused-by-the-difference-between-let-and-let-in-scheme/15006018#15006018

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `let*` form is a series of nested `lambda`s. For example, this:

```
(let* ((a 10)
       (b (+ 10 a)))
  (+ a b))
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
((lambda (a)
   ((lambda (b)
      (+ a b))
    (+ 10 a)))
 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes a lot of sense now!

Answer (score 4):

Since you are not wondering about the 'regular' `let`, if a `let*` can be converted into `let` then you will have your answer.  Therefore know that:

```
(let* ((a ...) (b ...) (c ...)) body ...)
```

is equivalent to:

```
(let ((a ...))
  (let ((b ...))
    (let ((c ...))
      body ...)))
```

(see R5RS, page 44, `(define-syntax let* ...)`). Now, given this, and knowledge that:

```
  (let ((a ...)) body ...)
```

is equivalent to:

```
  ((lambda (a) body ...) ...)
```

the 'expansion' of the `let*` that I showed above becomes:

```
  ((lambda (a)
     ((lambda (b)
        ((lambda (c)
           body ...)
          <c-init>))
      <b-init>))
   <a-init>)
```