# How to implement let* using lambda

Tags: lambda, scheme, lambda-calculus, let

I am doing lambda calculus and in my textbook, it says how would your write `let*` using lambda calculus.

My answers: x, y and z are the parameters; v1, v2 and v3 the arguments; e is the body:

```
((lambda (x y z) (e)) v1 v2 v3)
```

Answer in the book:

```
  ((lambda(x)
    ((lambda(y)
      ((lambda(z) e) v3))
      v2))
    v1)
```

I'm not sure if my answer is equivalent. If not, why is my answer wrong and how can the original answer be derived?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to express let\* as a lambda expression (not the regular let)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698548/how-to-express-let-as-a-lambda-expression-not-the-regular-let)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Update 2: I've realized that my original answer was correct and rolled back to the original, but will add some clarifying notes*.

In Scheme, `let*` allows later values to depend on earlier ones. So for instance, you can write (in the usual syntax):

```
(let* ((foo 3)
       (bar (+ foo 1))
       (baz (* bar 2)))
  (* foo bar baz))
```

which binds `foo` to 3, `bar` to 4, `baz` to 8, and returns 72. Your textbook's implementation allows for this.

However, your implementation doesn't allow this- it requires all the values to be evaluated independently. It is, however, a correct implementation of `let`, just not of `let*`.

The way your textbook's answer works is that the earlier values are bound before later ones.
So for instance, the above code in the textbook's implementation is as follows:

```
((lambda (foo)
  ((lambda (bar)
    ((lambda (baz) (* foo bar baz)) (* bar 2)))
    (+ foo 1)))
  3)
```

However, if you try to use your implementation in the same way:

```
((lambda (foo bar baz) (* foo bar baz)) 8 (+ foo 1) (* bar 2))
; Error - foo and bar aren't bound
```

then the `foo` in `(+ foo 1)` will be unbound, as `foo` isn't in scope there (same for the `bar` in `(* bar 2)`.

---

As a side note, the `(e)` in your implementation should really just be `e`, as in the textbook's implementation; the former is a thunk call, while the latter is just an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Istvan's answer is correct, but basically, the difference between your code and your textbook's is the difference between `let` and `let*`. Basically, `let*` is a nested series of `let`s, and in fact, a typical definition of `let*` is as follows:

```
(define-syntax let*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ;; if no bindings, same as let
    ((let* () body ...)
     (let () body ...))

    ;; otherwise, take one binding, then nest the rest
    ((let* (binding next ...) body ...)
     (let (binding)
       (let* (next ...)
         body ...)))))
```