# Confused by let to lambda conversion

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, racket, let

I am currently, going through this [great article on Y-combinator](https://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html) by [Mike Vanier](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~mvanier/). Along the explanation the following line is dropped:

> It turns out that any let expression can be converted into an equivalent lambda expression using this equation:
>
> `(let ((x <expr1>)) <expr2>)
>     ==> ((lambda (x) <expr2>) <expr1>)`

The article illustrates this statement by converting:

```
(define (part-factorial self)
  (let ((f (self self)))
    (lambda (n)
      (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (f (- n 1)))))))
```

to:

```
(define (part-factorial self)
  ((lambda (f)
    (lambda (n)
      (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (f (- n 1))))))
  (self self)))
```

Now, I understand how and why two code snippets above are identical, though I can't get my head around the fact that general equation for converting `let` to `lambda` is:

```
(let ((x <expr1>)) <expr2>)
==> ((lambda (x) <expr2>) <expr1>)
```

I'd appreciate the elaborate explanation.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698548/how-to-express-let-as-a-lambda-expression-not-the-regular-let).

Comment: re: the article's epigraph, apparently it was John von Neumann who said, "in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let` lets you open a new environment in which variables are available. In programming language terms we say it "opens a new frame".

When you write `(let ((x 42)) <body>)` you create a frame in which `x` is available inside `<body>`, and assign it the value `42`.

Well, there is another tool that lets you open new frames. In fact, it's usually the basic brick with which you can build more abstract constructs: it is called `lambda`.

`lambda` opens a new frame in which its arguments are available to its body.
When you write `(lambda (x) <body>)` you make `x` available to the `<body>` of the function.

The only difference between `lambda` and `let` is that `let` immediately assigns a value to `x`, while `lambda` awaits the value as an argument.

Therefore, if you want to wrap a `<body>` with a directly assigned value using `lambda`, you just have to pass that value!

```
((lambda (x) <body>) 42)
```

Which makes it exactly equivalent to:

```
(let ((x 42)) <body>)
```

Answer (score 5):

I've ended up figuring it out myself =).

The point that I was missing is that in:

```
(let ((x <expr1>)) <expr2>)
==> ((lambda (x) <expr2>) <expr1>)
```

`x` is present, somewhere, inside `<expr2>`, so it's more like:

```
(let ((x <expr1>)) <expr-containing-x>)
==> ((lambda (x) <expr-containing-x>) <expr1>)
```

With that being said, if we will substitute `x` for `f` in:

```
(define (part-factorial self)
  (let ((f (self self)))
    (lambda (n)
      (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (f (- n 1)))))))
```

as well as in:

```
(define (part-factorial self)
  ((lambda (f)
    (lambda (n)
      (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (f (- n 1))))))
  (self self)))
```

and will highlight `x`, `<expr1>` and `<expr2>` with different colors, the conversion formula should become clear then:

[image: x, <expr1> and <expr2> highlighted]

Comment: `x` doesn't need to be used anywhere - `(let ((x 0)) 99)` is the same as `((lambda (x) 99) 0)`.

Comment: for me, it's the other way around: `(x => ...x...) val` *"means"* `let {x = val} in ...x... ` which is self-explanatory *("open up a fresh environment frame; set up a place called `x` in it; put the value of `val` in that place; proceed...").*

Comment: Examples should use more meaningful names. Would you have been confused by this: `((lambda (param) body ...)  arg) <--> (let ((param arg)) body ...)`?

Answer (score 5):

You should imagine having a very little lisp language that has `lambda` but not `let`. You want to do:

```
(let ((nsq (square n)))
  (+ nsq nsq))
```

You know that `nsq` is a new variable and that the body of the `let` could be made a function:

```
(lambda (nsq) (+ nsq nsq))
```

Then you need to use that to get the same value:

```
((lambda (nsq) (+ nsq nsq)) (square n))
```

Imagine that your simple scheme has macros and thus, you implement as `let`:

```
(define-syntax let
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(let ((binding value) ...)
       body ...)
     ((lambda (binding ...)
        body ...)
      value ...)]))
```

Note, that in many implementations this actually happens exactly this way.