# Avoiding double call of funcall

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, common-lisp

> Consider the following function definition in Lisp:
>
> ```
> (defun Fct(F L)
>     (cond
>         ((null L) nil)
>         ((funcall F (car L)) (cons (funcall F (car L)) (Fct F (cdr L)) ) )
>         (T nil)
>     )
> )
> ```
>
> Give a solution to avoid the double call `(funcall F (car L))`.You
> wil not use set,setq,setf. Justify the answer.

This is how I redefined the function:

```
(defun Fct2(F L)
    (funcall #'(lambda (x)
                    (cond
                        ((null L) nil)
                        (x (cons x (Fct2 F (cdr L)) ) )
                        (T nil)
                    )
                )
        (F (car L))
    )
)
```

I works, but I can't see if there is no more double call behind. Also I have seen someone who did it in another way:

```
(defun redefine(f l)
    (funcall #' (lambda (x)                    
                        (cond 
                            ((null l) nil)
                            (x (cons x (Fct f (cdr l))))
                            (t nil)
                        )                   
                )
                (funcall f (car l))
    )
)
```

(using the old Fct inside)

But I think that Fct2 is the good way to proceed. I'd like to hear some opinions.

Comment: What you are doing with the lambda expression in `Fct2` [is equivalent to using a `let` form.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49455384/6879826)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fct` takes a function `f` and a list `L` as arguments
and returns a list of `t`s for the elements of `L` which evaluate to a true value for `f`  un
til either `L` is exhausted, or an element evaluates to false for `F`.

For example:

```lisp
(fct #'plusp '(1 2 -3 4 10)) => (t t),
(fct #'listp '((1 2 3) 4 '(a))) => (t),
(fct #'listp nil) => nil.
```

The functions `fct2` and `redefine` do not satisfy this behaviour.

In other to avoid evaluating an expression multiple times,
simply bind the result of evaluating the expression to a symbol.
Consider the following implementation which achieves the desired result:

```lisp
(defun fct-2 (func list)
  (when list
    (let ((head (funcall func (car list))))
      (when head
        (cons head (fct-2 func (cdr list)))))))
```

The macro `when` is especially useful when you have an if form with no else part.
In `fct-2`, we bind the result of `(funcall func (car list))` to
`head` which we use later.

Side notes:

1. Commonlisp has separate name spaces for functions and variables so we can use names like  `list` as variable names with no problems, this can lead to clearer programs instead of names
   like `L` for lists.
2. Check out [https://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt](https://mumble.net/%7Ecampbell/scheme/style.txt) and https://lisp-lang.org/style-guide/ for guides on writing and formatting (common)lisp programs.