# Difference between let and let* in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Consider the following macro:

```
(defmacro somemacro []
    (list 'let ['somevar "Value"] 'somevar))
```

Expanding it yields the following result:

```
(macroexpand '(somemacro))
```

Result:

```
(let* [somevar "Value"] somevar)
```

I have two questions about let* (with the asterisk):

- What does it mean? (In particular: is it documented somewhere?)
- Why is the macro not expanded with the 'normal' let? (I.e., let without the asterisk.) Both yield the same result (in my experimentation). Is there a counter example?

Unluckily I could not find any 'official' documentation about let*, that's why I'm asking here.

Sources I've already considered:

```
(doc let*)  ; --> nil
(source let*)  ; --> source not found
```

1. https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core  --> I see not let* here
   (although there is e.g. list*)
2. https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let --> only mentioned once in
   a comment, that is not totally clear to me:

   > Nota Bene: let in Clojure is like let* in Scheme -- each init-expr has access to the preceding binding forms. (There is also a let*, but it is more or less let without destructuring, and in fact is the underlying implementation.)
3. [LET versus LET* in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554949/let-versus-let-in-common-lisp)
   --> this question is about common lisp, but maybe it's the same in Clojure?
4. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5084339/3398271

   > In Clojure it basically means "foo* is like foo, but somehow different, and you probably want foo". In other words, it means that the author of that code couldn't come up with a better name for the second function, so they just slapped a star on it.

--> Is this the case for let and let*? But if so, still the question remains, what is exactly the difference?

5. [What is the difference between let and let* in Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866064/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-let-in-scheme) --> Is this the same in Clojure?

Comment: There is apparently also an `if` and `if*` pair.  As with `let`, documentation is not easy to find.  I am not aware that `if` destructures, so something else must be going on.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin,Interesting. With `if*` not being documented it probably is internal and not meant for consumption. I looked at the Clojure source on GitHub, but GitHub's search stripped `*` out. There are lots of cases of `if`. I suppose the answer is to download the source locally and run `grep` locally.

Comment: Clojure has no equivalent of Scheme's `let`. Clojure's `let` has the semantics of Scheme's `let*`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`let*` is an internal implementation detail. `let` is a macro implemented in terms of `let*`. https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4301

The macro `let` adds parameter [destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20(Destructuring)) to `let*`. This is the standard pattern for `xyz` and `xyz*` in Clojure, with the `*` version not being documented. An exception being [`list`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/list) and [`list*`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/list*).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I tried it out and, in fact `(let [[a b c & d :as e] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]] [a b c d e])` works, whilst `(let* [[a b c & d :as e] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]] [a b c d e])` causes a CompilerException.

Comment: I might not have been clear. `let*` does not have destructuring. The `let` macro calls `let*`, providing destructuring in the process.

Comment: Yes, I fully understood it (what I meant, is that I found an example which proves exactly this :) ) Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would add that the reason why `macroexpand` returns `let*` instead of `let` can be found in the [documentation of `macroexpand`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/macroexpand):

> Repeatedly calls macroexpand-1 on form until it no longer
>   represents a macro form, then returns it.

So what happens is the first call of `macroexpand-1` returns `(let [somevar "Value"] somevar)`, and the second expands `let` into `let*`.

Indeed,

```
user=> (println (clojure.string/join "\n" (take 3 (iterate macroexpand-1 '(somemacro)))))
(somemacro)
(let [somevar "Value"] somevar)
(let* [somevar "Value"] somevar)
nil
```

If you were to use destructuring in your macro, the output would be more interesting:

```
user=> (defmacro destructuring-macro [] `(let [[x y z] [:x :y :z]] y))
#'user/destructuring-macro

user=> (println (clojure.string/join "\n" (take 3 (iterate macroexpand-1 '(destructuring-macro)))))
(destructuring-macro)
(clojure.core/let [[testing.core/x testing.core/y testing.core/z] [:x :y :z]] testing.core/y)
(let* [vec__8356 [:x :y :z] x (clojure.core/nth vec__8356 0 nil) y (clojure.core/nth vec__8356 1 nil) z (clojure.core/nth vec__8356 2 nil)] testing.core/y)
nil
```

Notice that `let` is fully qualified by the syntax quote, because it is not a special form (even though its documentation says it is). The underlying special form is `let*`, which is not fully qualified by the syntax quote.