# scheme: order of internal definition

Tags: scheme

It's a problem in SICP book ch4,here is the code

```
(let ((a 1))
  (define (f x)
    (define b (+ a x))
    (define a 5)
    (+ a b))
  (f 10))
```

the error message is “a: undefined; cannot use before initialization”,if I use lambda expression

```
((lambda (a)
  (define (f x)
    (define a 5)
    (define b (+ a x))
    (+ a b))
  (f 10)) 1)
```

still dont work,but if I write this as procedure define,like this

```
(define (f a)
  (define (g x)
    (define b (+ a x))
    (+ a b))
  (g 10))
(f 1)
```

it runs without error,but these two are basically the same right? why the let and lambda expression failed? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because it refers to the inner `a`, not the one in the `let`:

```
(let ((a 1))
  (define (f x)
    (define b (+ a x))   ; `a` here refers to
    (define a 5)         ;    **this one**
    (+ a b))
  (f 10))
```

Internal `define`s are all placed in one *shared* *scope*. It is done so we can define mutually recursive functions.

If you switch the order of the two `define`s it'll work (put `a` definition above the `b` definition) because then `a` will be initialized before being used in the `b` initialization, but only if you use `#lang racket`.

In `#lang sicp` the following works:

```
(let ((a 1))
  (define (f x)
    (define a 5)
    (define b (lambda () (+ a x)))
    (+ a (b)))
  (f 10))
```

Comment: Hi,I put the a definiton above b definiton as you said,but it still shows the same error (I use #lang sicp write this in DrRacket)

Comment: just checked the `#lang sicp` indeed it throws an error. I guess it follows the `#lang r5rs`'s lead on this. nested defines are effectively in the shared `letrec`, and in R5RS it is forbidden to reference the value of letrec variable during initialiation.

Comment: ok...a silly question,why in b definition, the interpreter doesn't find a in let (a 1) ? I'm really comfused, thanks for helping me

Comment: because you defined it to reference `a`, and there is an `a` in the inner scope, same scope where `b` is defined. put this code in Dr Racket, hover with your mouse of variables, it draws nice arrows to show what definition is referenced by which variable.

Comment: so the internal definiton are evaluated at the same time instead of sequentially right?

Comment: @WillNess racket is not scheme, this is why it works.

Comment: @zenxy depends on the language specification. right now you have three: R5RS scheme, sicp, racket. see more e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15006018/849891).